# Category from Finding DISTINCT COUNT of Client

Tags: powerbi, distinct-values

I have a similar Table like this:

```
Country, Client, Item, Price
C1, A1, B1, 10
C1, A1, B1, 7
C1, A1, B2, 5
C1, A2, B1, 0
C1, A2, B2, 20
C2, A3, B1, 8
C2, A3, B3, 7
C2, A3, B4, 4
C2, A3, B5, 3
C2, A4, B1, 9
C2, A4, B1, 9
```

I'd like to find the DISTINCT COUNT of Items by Client and find how many Clients from Country buy only one Item, two Items, three Items and so on (like Category)..  as below:

```
Country, **1, **2, **3, **4
C1 => 0, 2, 0, 0
C2 => 1, 0, 0, 1

** Number of client who buy (1 or 2 or 3 or 4) DISTINCT Items
```

For example, in C1 are Client (A1) who bought 3 Items, but only 2 are Distinct and Client (A2) who bought 2 Items ( also 2 Distinct).

It means, that I have 2 Client in C1, who bought 2 Distinct Items.

How do I create a Measure in Power BI Desktop to achieve this?

Thank you for your answers/suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a measure in the report view (Right click on your dataset fields > Add Measure)

```
Measure = Distinctcount(YourTable[Item])
```

If you add a table to your report and select Country, Client, Item, Price this measure will always display `1`.

If you add only Client and Item to the table this measure will display the distinct values.

If you want fix vales in your measure you can use the following code:

```
MeasureFix = Calculate(DistinctCount(YourTable[Item]); YourTable[Country] = "C1")
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer Strawberryshrub. But I think you did not understand what I want to achieve. I need to count how many clients in each Country buy only ONE DISTINCT items, TWO, THREE...

Comment: For example, only two clients buy 7 dictinct items in country C1. I need to show that for C1 and Category **7 => 2 (Count of clients). But I dont know, how I can create dynamic category ( **7) from the result of DISTINCT measure.

Comment: Well basically you create a measure like my first expression. The filtering happens in the table/chart, the same goes for the cathegory. If you add a chart and use the measre as value **AND** as x-/ or y-Axis value Power-BI creates automatically the cathegory based on the measure, which would be in this case `1, 2, 3, ... itmes`

Comment: Sorry, I tried your solution, but doesnt work for my case (or I dont get it). Here is my first half of solution: `CountDistinctClients = SUMX(SUMMARIZE('Table1';'Table1'[Client];"ABCD";DISTINCTCOUNT('Table1'[Item]));[ABCD])`   This measure count number of Clients who bought at least one Item. Next step is categorize them based on number of Distinct items, 
which they bought.

Comment: I can create measures, where I add "IF" function for filtered (for example) Client who bought only one Distinct items:  `NumberOfClient_(who bought 1Distinct items)= SUMX(SUMMARIZE('Table1';'Table1'[Client];"ABCD";IF(DISTINCTCOUNT('Table1 '[Item])=1;1;0));[ABCD])`  or for 2 Distinct Items `NumberOfClient_(who bought 2Distinct items)= SUMX(SUMMARIZE('Table1';'Table1'[Client];"ABCD";IF(DISTINCTCOUNT('Table1 '[Item])=2;1;0));[ABCD])`  But is there way to make it easier and interactive?

Comment: If the first part works for you then leave it. You can simplify the second with a `Switch()` function. Like this: `Measure2 = SWITCH([CountDistinctClients];1;"Categ1";2;"Categ2";3;"Categ3";4;"Categ4";"CategElse")`